# Sprites are distorted when scaled

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have a game I'm working on with Phaser 3, and I have an icon for a sword in the player's inventory:

[image]

But when I scale it using `sprite.setScale(0.5)`, I get this monstrosity:
[image]

Any idea why this happens? thanks!

Comment: i cannot explain how to fix it, but it looks like the pixels are trying to push eachother

Comment: seems like it, it could be used as a damaged sword tho. still looks cool

Comment: That was actually the idea for the starting weapon, so i mean I could pass it off as intentional if I can't figure it out or am just feeling lazy.

Comment: @MrToenails hi.:) I saw your question already, and was looking for a interesting solution. but there is no "good" solution (atleast I could fine none). best option is to make two different images. Option 2 just try out different scaling values until you find one that doesnt distort the image multiple of 2 works usually. But you could also post on https://phaser.discourse.group/ there you can find some phaser experts. I hope it helps.

Comment: p.s.: for scaling try to select a value, where the resulting `displayWidth` / `displayHeight` is an integer / a whole number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so the problem seems to be fixed by making sure the end value for the height and width values were integers, my actual code for scaling was `sprite.setScale(0.45)`, and changing the value to 0.5 was a quick fix, getting the much improved end result of this: 
[image]

PS: Thanks to @winner_joiner for the suggestion

Comment: btw.: if you are **not** going for a `pixel-art` style you could you turn `antialias` on, in the documentation [link to the documentation](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.52.0/focus/Phaser.Core.Config-antialias), but this _could_ make all images abit blurry and so.